# Pyspark SQL WHERE NOT IN?

Tags: python, sql, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to find everything that is in `nodes2` but not `nodes1`.

```
spark.sql("""
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM 
    (SELECT * FROM nodes2 WHERE NOT IN  
    (SELECT * FROM nodes1))
""").show()
```

Getting the following error:
`"cannot resolve '`NOT`' given input columns: [nodes2.~id, nodes2.~label];`

Is it possible to do this sort of set difference operation in Pyspark?

Comment: added relevant tags for visibility

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Matching single column with NOT IN:**

Do you need to define some columns with where? which you trying to match for NOT operator?

If that is the case, then, for example, you want to check `id`

```
spark.sql("""
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM 
    (SELECT * FROM nodes2 WHERE id NOT IN  
    (SELECT id FROM nodes1))
""").show()
```

**Matching multiple columns (or complete row) with NOT IN:**

Or if you really want to match complete row (all columns), use something like [concat](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#concat) on all columns to match

```
spark.sql("""
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM 
    (SELECT * FROM nodes2 as WHERE CONCAT(id,label) NOT IN (SELECT CONCAT(id,label) FROM nodes1))
""").show()
```

or with alias

```
spark.sql("""
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM 
    (SELECT * FROM nodes2 n2 as WHERE CONCAT(n2.id,n2.label) NOT IN (SELECT CONCAT(n1.id,n1.label) FROM nodes1 n1))
""").show()
```

Comment: Is it possible to do a complete row comparison on all columns?

Comment: I have updated the answer